# define grandma prolog by given conditions

Tags: prolog

Write Prolog code to define grandmother. This is either your mother's mother or your father's mother. Do this using only: grandmotherOf(X,Y) (which you are defining), motherOf(X,Y), and fatherOf(X,Y).

Comment: Write question (code) that shows what is not working with your attempt. Do this using only English(modern) and Prolog(standard).

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take the time to read the [online help](https://stackoverflow.com/help) to learn how to ask a good question and get the most out of the site.

Answer (score 3):

grandmotherOf(X,Y) - I would translate this to grandmother of X is Y, so Y=grandmother and X=grandchild.

grandmother means that its the mother of either your father or mother
so if Y is your grandmother and X are you

```
grandmotherOf(X,Y):- motherOf(X,Z), motherOf(Z,Y).
grandmotherOf(X,Y):- fatherOf(X,Z), motherOf(Z,Y).
```

The first line solves the case of the grandmother from your mothers side, if it fails (it finds no Z that is your mother and is the daughter of your grandmother) goes on the second case and looks for a father.

Comment: Your code is correct but in general we like to discourage people from asking us to do their homework without any apparent attempt to try it themselves at all.

Comment: Oh, I should also say, aesthetically, I like to use variables so the alphabetic order helps make it more obvious what is going on, so I would probably do `grandmother_of(X, Z) :- mother_of(X, Y), mother_of(Y, Z).`